# How to achieve less zealous indentation in Python?

Tags: indentation, python

I'm experiencing frustrating behaviour with automatic Python indentation when ending a highly indented block. I've used pilcrows to indicate where I want newlines in the following example:

```
def f():
    if True:
        if True:
            if True:
                print ""
¶
¶
¶
def g():
    print ""
```

After finishing typing the first function, every subsequent line is automatically indented by 16 spaces, which all need to be deleted. I understand that the first time I hit return, indenting to that level makes sense. But I am surprised that when hitting return on an unindented line it would also be assumed that I wanted the maximum valid indentation.

This behaviour seems to occur in 24.4.1 with both the new `python.el` (Gallina) and `python-mode.el`. (It also appeared to happen when I tried to use the old `python.el` by Dave Love, but I could not work out how to verify which `python.el` had actually loaded). I note that with the new `python.el` I can use `C-j` to return without indenting, but that doesn't help much with a situation such as the following:

```
def f():
    if True:
        if True:
            if True:
                print ""
    ¶
    print ""
```

I don't want to disable automatic indentation, but is there a way to make it less aggressive and accept valid lower levels of indentation somehow?

Answer (score 2):

With python-mode.el each block may have it's own length of indent-step, i.e. the value of `py-indent-offset`.

`py-smart-indentation` must be on.

When introducing a new block, the desired indentation needs to be set/correct on the first indented line. With the next line, the new distance should have been learned.

In case of error, please file a bug-report here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Comment: This works in the Emacs GUI, but it's not working for me when running in the terminal with `emacs --no-window-system`. I shall investigate further and file a bug if necessary.